# Else condition not working while using has_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I've been trying to develop a recent posts widget which will display my most recent posts in sidebar. I am trying to display default "ft-thumb.jpg" image if there is no post thumbnail but its not working. Here is my code -

```
public function widget($args,$instance) {
        //displays our widget
        extract($args);
        extract($instance);
        $number = $instance['number'];
        echo $before_widget;
           if(!$title) {
            echo '<div class="widget-title"><h2>Recent Posts</h2></div>';
           } 
           else {
            echo $before_title .$title. $after_title;
           }
           $popular_posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => $number,'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),'orderby' => 'desc'));
           if($popular_posts->have_posts()) {
            while($popular_posts->have_posts()) {
                $popular_posts->the_post(); global $post;
                $link = get_permalink();
                $url = get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )."/images/ft-thumb.jpg";
                echo "<div class='row'>" . "<div class='col-md-12  widget-recent-post'>";

                    echo "<div class='rc-post-image'>";
                    if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
                        echo "<a href=$link><img src=$image[0]" . " width='98' height='80' class='img-responsive' /></a>";
                    } else {echo "<img src=$url >";}

                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "<div class='rc-post-area'>";
                        echo "<h3><a href=$link>";
                        the_title(); 
                        echo "</a></h3>";
                        echo "<div class='post-meta'><span class='date-meta'>On <a href=$link>";
                        the_time(get_option('date_format'));
                        echo "</a></span></div>";
                    echo "</div>";

                echo "</div></div>";
            }
           }
        echo $after_widget;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain "it's not working". Many issues here, e.g. you're not closing the tag: `<img src=$url`

Comment: `} else {echo "<img src=$url>";}`

Comment: sorry it's just error in copying code, I am closing the tag still its not working.. I am getting above result like in screenshot.

Comment: You need to take another screenshot now that you have closed the tag, so we can see the new error.

Comment: I checked its same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not quoting your HTML attributes - one section should be:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
    echo "<a href='$link'><img src='$image[0]' width='98' height='80' class='img-responsive' /></a>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='$url' >";
}
```

...the other should be:

```
echo "<h3><a href='$link'>";
the_title(); 
echo "</a></h3>";
echo "<div class='post-meta'><span class='date-meta'>On <a href='$link'>";
the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) );
echo "</a></span></div>";
```

Comment: else { echo "<img src='$url' >";} only this condition not working, rest is all fine..